# can't resume or rebase stream on snapshot view on windows

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I am trying to rebase a stream with a particular view but it is not letting me to rebase saying "change sets are not empty" while rebasing from windows GUI but if I look at the sepecific rebase activity which is set to rebase, there is no change set on it. And when I tried to rebase from cmd, it gives me an error saying "rebase doesn't match the specified view and ....is not the view where you have started the operation". I don't remember that I have started the rebase opeartion in aother view.

What is best way to deal with it?

PS: I can't cancel or resume or complete the rebase opeartion here.

Answer (score 0):

A `cleartool rebase -status -stream StreamBeingRebased@\apvob` should give you the name of the view currently used.

If that view doesn't exist anymore, and if you are in ClearCase 7.1+, you can try a:

```
cleartool rebase -resume -reset -to newviewtag
```

That would try and resume the rebase using a new view.
I would recommend for that new view to be a dynamic one, instead of a snapshot one: it is quicker to start and succeed/fail, and you can do multiple tests without waiting for the view to update itself (update being done only in a snapshot view).