# Cancel or complete a rebase operation in UCM

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I had a dynamic view and I started a re-base operation on that view, then before doing a `cleartool rebase -complete` I removed that view accidentally!

Now the problem is that I cannot do a `rebase -complete` or `rebase -cancel` in another view attached to the same stream.
How can I resolve this issue, I get the following error:

```
cleartool: Error: No tag in region for view "00000000.00000000.0000.00:00:00:00:00:00".
cleartool: Error: Unable to start view "".
cleartool: Error: Unable to cancel rebase.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`cleartool rebase`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_rebase.htm?lang=en), you can try and resuming the operation with a new view (which should be attached to the same destination stream)

```
cleartool rebase -resume -reset -view aNewUCMView
```

that would be using the option:

```
-reset -vie/w new-development-view_tag
```

> Resets the target view to a new development view.
>   **Use this option should the target view become inaccessible**.

As in "[Can't resume or rebase stream on snapshot view on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16805979/6309)":

> I would recommend for that new view to be a dynamic one, instead of a snapshot one: it is quicker to start and succeed/fail, and you can do multiple tests without waiting for the view to update itself (update being done only in a snapshot view).

---

If you see:

```
cleartool: Error: The view cannot be retargeted because 
the current integration activity "rebase.STREAM_NAME.20141124.170858" 
has checkouts.
```

You will have to unco everything (see first "[How to find all checkedout files with ClearCase cleartool?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3094806/6309)"), and then:

```
cleartool rebase -cancel -reset -view aNewUCMView
```

Comment: Old CC 7.0.x required quite a few ops to cancel a rebase (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146614). But if you are using a more recent ClearCase, you shouldn't have to resort to those.

Comment: I am getting this now: cleartool: Error: The view cannot be retargeted because the current integration activity "rebase.STREAM_NAME.20141124.170858" has checkouts.

Comment: Is there a way to cancel all my checkouts everywhere using one command?

Comment: @coffeMug it is important to try and resume first. Don't cancel any checkout unless you are sure you want to cancel the rebase itself.

Comment: Do you know a command to list mycheckouts in the current view?